# Regex expression to exclude any number from any place

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, python-re

I have a code which takes a string as input and discards all the letters and prints only the numbers which doesn't contain 9 at any of the place.
I have decided to do it with the help of regex but couldn't find a working expression to achieve it where it is needed to be modified?

I have also tried with `[^9]` but it doesn't work.

```
import re

s = input().lstrip().rstrip()
updatedStr = s.replace(' ', '')
nums = re.findall('[0-8][0-8]', updatedStr)
print(nums)
```

The code should completely discard the number which contains 9 at any place.

for example - if the input is:

```
"This is 67 and 98"
```

output: `['67']`

input:

```
"This is the number 678975 or 56783 or 87290 thats it"
```

output: `['56783']` (as the other two numbers contain 9 at some places)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try using:

```
nums=re.findall('[0-8]+',updatedStr)
```

Instead.

**[0-8]+** means "*one or more ocurrences of a number from 0 to 8"*

I tried : 12313491 a asfasgf 12340 asfasf 123159

And got: ['123134', '1', '12340', '12315']

(Your code returns the array. If you want to join the numbers you should add some code)

Comment: it doesn't work as it is printing the numbers which contains digit 9 along with the numbers that doesn't contain 9

Comment: You're right. In that case, maybe this regex could help you: \b[^9a-zA-Z.,\s]+\b   If you try it on https://regexr.com you'll get the results you're looking for. Then we'll see how Python's *re* library responds to that

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you wan't to match all numbers that don't contain a 9.
Your pattern should match any string of digits that doesn't contain a nine but ends and starts with a non-digit

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=[^\d])[0-8]+(?=[^\d])')
pattern.findall(inputString) # Finds all the matches
```

Here the pattern is doing a couple of things.

1. (?<=...) is a positive look behind. This means we will only get matches that have a non digit before it.
2. [0-8]+ will match 1 or more digits except 9
3. (?=...) is a lookahead. We will only get matches that end in a non digit.

### Note:

inputString does not need to be stripped. And in fact this pattern may run into issues if there is a number at the beginning or end of a string. To prevent this. simply pad it with any chars.

```
inputString = ' ' + inputString + ' '
```

Look at the python [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more info